# Как добавить в бота в телеграме напоминания и обратный отчет до нужного дня с помощью datetime?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, datetime, telebot

Возможно вопрос покажется глупым, нужно сделать так, чтобы на определенную дату бот отправлял сообщение и чтобы на сообщение от пользователя, учитывая сегодняшнюю дату, отсылал сообщение с кол-вом дней до какого-то дня.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы отправлять сообщение с кол-вом оставшихся дней можно использовать `datetime.timedelta` 
Чтобы отправлять отправить сообщение в определённый день можно использовать scheduler, например `Advanced python scheduler`. Добавить туда функцию, которая будет запускаться, например, раз в день, и проверять текущую дату. И когда она совпадёт с нужной, отправит сообщение
https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/v2.1.2/#installing-apscheduler